# Change in $0 Perl variable on new server

Tags: perl, path

I recently migrated to a new server due to hardware issues.  The old server ran Centos 7 as does the new one.  I don't remember for sure the Perl version on the old server but I believe it was the same as the new one (5.16.3).  All of my Perl scripts run fine on the new server with one difference however. The $0 variable on the old server returned just the script name, however, on the new server it returns the full path along with the script name.

Does anyone know if there is a configuration setting some place that controls this or why Perl would set this variable differently on the new server vs. the old server?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these scripts you are running from the command line, or some other way?

Comment: These scripts are being run as CGI scripts from various forms, or launched directly when a link is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

`$0` is exactly the file name argument provided to `perl`.

```
$ cat a.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature qw( say );
say $0;

$ perl a.pl
a.pl

$ perl ./a.pl
./a.pl

$ perl ././././a.pl
././././a.pl

$ perl /home/ikegami/a.pl
/home/ikegami/a.pl
```

If the script is run as executable, this is usually exactly what was provided to `exec` to execute the program.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$ a.pl
./a.pl          <-- "." comes from $PATH.

$ ./a.pl
./a.pl

$ ././././a.pl
././././a.pl

$ /home/ikegami/a.pl
/home/ikegami/a.pl
```

If you want just the program name, you can use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Basename)'s `basename`.

For example,

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

sub usage {
   warn(@_) if @_;
   my $prog = basename($0);
   warn("Try `$prog --help' for help\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

---

1. In particular, expect something weird for setuid scripts.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm still confused as to why it would change from one server to the next if the scripts themselves had not changed, and they are being run the same way; that is, as CGI scripts from forms, or directly from links.

Comment: As the answer points out, you'll have to check what executes the script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  I can just execute the script from my browser by typing the URL for the script on the server  in order to execute it.  I don't understand enough about the server internals to know *what* is executing the script on the server... Apache, maybe?

Comment: I'm saying it has nothing to do with Perl. If your web server is executing the script, then it's the one providing the value for `$0`. But more importantly, I'm also saying you should always have expected a path rather than a file name, and I provided the means of obtain the filename from the path. So what's the problem?

Comment: My old server (same CentOS7 OS, slightly different cPanel version) provided $0 as file name only, no path.  Regardless of whether I should have expected a full path and treated $0 as such, it *did* provide it as a bare filename,and I am capable of adjusting my code to compensate for the difference (and have successfully done so). What I was trying to determine was if anyone knew what configuration change on the server (config file settings, etc) might account for the difference between why the old server provided it one way and the new server provides it this way.

Comment: You are mistaken. Your old server provided a path. Your buggy code happened to work because the path happened to be a file name, but the bug has always been yours. /// As I already told you, this isn't a difference in Perl. I'm not sure why you care why your web server provides a different path than before, but it's your web server you'll need to check for differences.

Comment: I'm confused by this.  After discovering the difference, I ran a simple Perl script that did nothing but print $0 on the old server and ran the same script on the new server.  On the old one it printed the filename and on the new one it printed the full path and filename.  I don't see how it's my "buggy" Perl code making the difference.

Comment: Thats not what I said. I said the code is buggy for expecting a file name.

Comment: Ok, I don't know where to find the "official" definition of what $0 is to contain (although I've seen statements around PerlMonks saying "it depends on the OS"), but let's say I admit that my code should always expect a full path and I need to extract the filename.  Ok, fixed.  Now I'm back to asking my question:  For a Perl script (called from a browser), what part of the server provides the script with the value it receives for $0?

Comment: @vdawg, the part that calls `exec`.